# Don't show database connection info during exception error

Tags: asp.net

We're using C# & ASP.NET.  There, we learned the database connection info was visible in the exception error message on DEV & PROD server.  That pose a security risk.  So I'm writing a script that would strip out the connection string info from the error message so it won't be seen by everyone.

I'm pretty sure there's a setting in web.config that would disallow showing the database connection string as well.  If you know how then feel free to show us the way.

Otherwise here's the script I wrote below but it wouldn't work because the error message isn't a database connection string but database objects instead & there may be ";" characters in the password as well.  So, I welcome better suggestions.

```
    public void EmailErrorMsgTest()
    {
        //var testcase = "A problem has occurred on this web site. Please try again.  If this error continues, please contact support.";
        var testcase = "Resolution of the dependency failed, type = 'DealerSoft.Service.Interfaces.IIdentityService', name = '(none)'.Exception occurred while: Calling constructor DealerSoft.DataAccess.DbContext(DealerSoft.DataAccess.IConnectionFactory connectionFactory, DealerSoft.Framework.Resolver.IUserResolverService userResolverService).Exception is: Exception - Data Source = foo.DealerSoftwebfoo.com,1200; Initial Catalog = DatabaseFoo; User ID = UserIdFoo; Password = PasswordFoo; MultipleActiveResultSets = true---------------------------------------------- - At the time of the exception, the container was: Resolving DealerSoft.Service.Interfaces.IIdentityService,(none)Resolving parameter 'repository' of constructor DealerSoft.Service.Services.IdentityService(DealerSoft.DataAccess.Repository.Repository repository, DealerSoft.DataAccess.IUnitOfWork unitOfWork) Resolving DealerSoft.DataAccess.Repository.Repository,(none)Resolving parameter 'context' of constructor DealerSoft.DataAccess.Repository.Repository(DealerSoft.DataAccess.DbContext context) Resolving DealerSoft.DataAccess.DbContext,(none)Calling constructor DealerSoft.DataAccess.DbContext(DealerSoft.DataAccess.IConnectionFactory connectionFactory, DealerSoft.Framework.Resolver.IUserResolverService userResolverService)";

        testcase = SecurityRiskErrorMessageCleanup(testcase);
    }

    private string SecurityRiskErrorMessageCleanup(string errorMessage)
    {
        int startPos = -1;
        int endPos = -1;
        var msg = errorMessage.ToLower();

        // Remove database connection string.
        startPos = msg.IndexOf(@"data source =");
        if (startPos >= 0)
        {
            var tmpPos = msg.IndexOf(@"password =", startPos + 1);
            endPos = msg.IndexOf(";", tmpPos + 1);
            if (endPos > startPos && startPos >= 0)
            {
                var tmpStr = errorMessage.Substring(startPos, (endPos - startPos) + 1);
                errorMessage = errorMessage.Replace(tmpStr, "");
            }
        }
        startPos = -1;
        endPos = -1;

        // Future cleanup.
        // N/A.

        return errorMessage;
    }
```

Comment: We don't know enough about the code that generates/catches the error but it looks to me like you should focus on NOT appending the connection string information to the error in the first place (unless of course you are using some third party component).

Answer (score 0):

In your web.config file, you can have settings where you can enable custom error page to show on `RemoteOnly` users, whereas local users will still see detail error page.

```
<system.web>
    <customErrors defaultRedirect="YourErrorPage.aspx"
                  mode="RemoteOnly">
      <error statusCode="500"
             redirect="SpecificErrorPage.aspx"/>
    </customErrors>
  </system.web>
```

Comment: You're going to have to add a bit more text to this answer to make it connect to the question asked...

Comment: While it is true that you can hide details of the error in this manner, this doesn't solve the real issue which is leaking of sensitive information into error messages.

Comment: ok, but error message will not be shown to the user. So will that object be available by any chance?